# Calculation of values of header expressions of for structure in C

Tags: c, loops

I have been working on Euler Project lately and I thought I might as well solve these problems modularly so I can add the functions to my personal library. When I made the code modular, I have seen some expressions that might be inefficient:

```
for( ; forCounter <= limit / number1 * number1; forCounter += number1)

for( ; forCounter <= limit / number2 * number2; forCounter += number2)

for( ; forCounter <= limit / (number1 * number2) * (number1 * number2); forCounter += number1 * number2)
```

Are these calculations done only one time or every single iteration? A close example to this would be the expression `int x = 5` in initialization section of header of a for loop. First time it gets declared and initialized but in other iterations it is just assigned the value.

Comment: As the problems become harder, it is unlikely you will solve them inside the "one minute rule" with any kind of formulaic solution. Each one has to hand crafted.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah you cant just solve them with the first or second thing that come to your mind (brute force). You have to analyz what the pattern is and come up with a general formula to decrease and conquer or transform and conquer.

Comment: Those three loops are functionally the same.  The use of `<=` is suspicious; it is more likely to lead to array overflows than the canonical `for (int var = 0; var < limit; var += inc)` type notation.  One issue is: do the values of `limit`, `number1` or `number2` change during the execution of the loop?  Can the compiler be sure of that?  If the numbers don't change (can't change), then the compiler can optimize the tests.  If the numbers could change, then the expressions have to be recomputed.  The `for (int x = 5; …; …)` loop only executes the `int x = 5` once, before the first iteration.

Comment: I handled the use of <=there was no problem there. When it comes to changing values no they stayed the same value the whole time. I was just calculating multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. So i calculated 3 and 5 then substracted 15 from those. Doesnt x = 5 keep re assign the value? Let me try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this is very inefficient because these calculations done on every single iteration (some time compiler can optimize code, if view that  `limit` , `number1` and `number2` is unchanged during loop time). but general rule - need calculate all constant (during loop time) expressions before loop but not every time in loop. so code must be like this:

```
ULONG n = limit / number1 * number1;
for( ; forCounter <= n; forCounter += number1) { ...}

ULONG m = number1 * number2, n  = limit / m * m;
for( ; forCounter <= n; forCounter += m) { ... }
```

**EDIT**

if limit , number1 and number2 is constant values 
for example

```
#define limit 999
#define number1 3
#define number2 5
```

`limit / number1 * number1` also constant expression, calculated at compiler time. in this case

```
for( ; forCounter <= limit / number1 * number1; forCounter += number1)
```

absolute normal and effective.

but if they variables like this:

```
ULONG limit, number1, number2;
```

`limit / number1 * number1` *can* be re-evaluated on every iteration. this is depended from compiler, optimization and where `limit, number1, number2` declared (in global scope or local in function) - are this variables can be changed during loop time. this may be and optimized auto but not guarantee. better always by self direct optimize code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At first i used 999 3 5 as limit number1 and number2. But then i wanted to save the program as a function so i can use it easily later. 

I have another question though. Lets think in assembly. When we have a static value like 3 or a static variable that has the value of 3. Does the microprocessor get that value from main memory everytime or does 3 stay there until loop is over.(this question might be stupid since we need to know which microprocessor we are working on. also micro processors dont work with medium or high level langauges. they work with assembly)

Comment: @AnılErturk - are `limit / number2 * number2` calculated on every iteration depended from compiler and optimization options. if no optimizations - every time. this may be and optimized auto but not guarantee. better always by self direct optimize code

Comment: @AnılErturk assembly language has no optimisation. It does exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: @WeatherVane - where here assembly language ?

Comment: I have another question. Which one is the better programming practice. Declaring the int n at the top or declaring it right before usage? Or does it change depending no what kinda variables we use? As far as i understand we declare the variables we use only for one line next to that line? Kinda like a local local variable.

Comment: @RbMm please ask the OP that, since he introduced the idea.

Comment: @AnılErturk - may be i not understand just - are limit, number1,number1 - constants or variables ? if constants - initial code is normal. when i answer i assume that this is **variables** . but in case this is const (*define*) - the `limit / number2 * number2` not calculated in loop but also const, calced at compiled time